# Start dask worker with local directory

Tags: python, dask

I'm having 6 python files which need to be transferred to the workers. I want to add workers dynamically. That is after I submit the task to the workers if I add a worker, will the tasks be assigned to the new worker? If so, the new worker should have the python files in its local directory. Though I start the worker with --local-directory option, it still creates a new directory within the mentioned dir. Is there a way to mention the dir as local directory where we have the python files?

Answer (score 0):

The `--local-directory` option will create a new directory where Dask will leave temporary files.

If you want to add another directory to your Python path, you might consider using a preload script, or a worker plugin.  See these docs for more information : https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/custom-startup.html

If you just want to upload some files into your workers, you might also consider the `Client.upload_file` method.

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there a limit on dask related to the number of tasks being submitted? I submitted 30K tasks to the scheduler and there are 9 workers. But the scheduler processed only ~4K tasks.

Comment: This comment seems entirely unrelated to the question and answer provided here.  Maybe you meant to ask a new question?

Comment: Yeah, @mrcoklin it's a new question.

Comment: Then you should ask a new question on Stack Overflow.  See the "Ask Question" button in the upper right of this page.

Comment: Thanks, you saved a million by identifying the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!